# Greedy and Randomized-Greedy Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am studying Algorithmic Game Theory and am totally new to the topic, but wanted to clarify some items (apologies for the length beforehand). My book of reference is [link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esandholm/cs15-892F13/algorithmic-game-theory.pdf).

On the topic of External Regret Minimization, in section 4.3.1, it is stated that "The Greedy Algorithm, for any sequence of losses has: $$L_{\text{Greedy}}^T\leq N\cdot L_{\min}^T+(N-1)$$
where initially: $x^1=1$, and at time $t$, $L_{\min}^{t-1}=\min_{i\in X}L_i^{t-1}$, $S^{t-1}=\{i:L_i^{t-1}=L_{\min}^{t-1}\}$, and $x^{t}=\min S^{t-1}$.

I tried to visualize this via an example, where I took:

**Initial Setup:**

- (N = 3) and five time steps (T = 5)
- Actions: ( X = {1, 2, 3} )
- Time steps: ( T = 5 )
- The Greedy algorithm will start by choosing action 1.

**Hypothetical Loss Vectors:**

- At each time step ( t ), the environment (or adversary) presents a loss vector for the actions. Let's say these are the loss vectors for each time step:

  - ( t=1 ): Loss Vector = ([0, 1, 1])
  - ( t=2 ): Loss Vector = ([1, 0, 1])
  - ( t=3 ): Loss Vector = ([1, 1, 0])
  - ( t=4 ): Loss Vector = ([0, 1, 1])
  - ( t=5 ): Loss Vector = ([1, 0, 0])

**Algorithm's Action and Loss:**

1. $t=1$, Greedy chooses $x^1 = 1$ and incurs no loss $\ell^1_1 = 0$.
2. $t=2$, Greedy still chooses $x^2 = 1$ as  $L^1_1 = 0$ which is the minimum loss so far, but now incurs a loss $\ell^2_1 = 1$.
3. $t=3$, Greedy chooses $x^3=2$ since $L_1^2=1 $ and $L_2^2=1$ but incurs loss of $\ell^3_2 = 1$.
4. $t=4$, Greedy sticks with action 2 as it has the minimum cumulative loss, but now incurs a loss $\ell^4_2 = 1$.
5. $t=5$, Greedy switches to action $x^5 = 3$, as action 2 now has a higher cumulative loss. Greedy incurs no loss $\ell^5_3 = 0$.

**Cumulative Loss for Greedy:**

- Total loss for Greedy: $L^5_{\text{Greedy}} =3$

**Best Single Action in Hindsight:**

- For action 1: $L^5_1 = 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 = 3$
- For action 2: $L^5_2 = 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3$
- For action 3: $L^5_3 = 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 3$
- Best single action loss: $L^T_{\min} = 3$ (as all actions have equal loss)

**Apply Theorem 4.2:**

- Theorem 4.2 states $L^T_{\text{Greedy}} \leq N \cdot L^T_{\min} + (N - 1)$.

The total loss of the Greedy algorithm over 5 time steps is indeed less than or equal to three times the best single action's loss plus two additional losses, validating Theorem 4.2 with this example.

Is this example right?